# PulseAudio default source changing for Kazam

Tags: pulseaudio

I have a strange issue with Pulse Audio Volume Control, when i start recording with Kazam, the following happens:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (Recording Started on Kazam)

[image]

The default recording device is Built-in Audio Analog Stereo, but i want it permanently to be Headset H340 Analog Stereo, which shows in the drop down and i have to select it repeatedly to change to H340 headset microphone. Please can anyone solve this issue. It was working fine before but do not know what caused it to break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of directly starting to record with keyboard shortcut, open the Kazam window, goto File -> Preferences. from there select the device you want to use for recording.